# SQL: Displaying and counting items in

Tags: sql, psql

I'm trying to count staff that belong to certain branch in sql, so branch X has Y number of employees for example. There are two tables I need to query number 1. and 2. below. I want to achieve the following:

branchno | number of staff in that branch

1. The 'Staff' table: **staffno |   fname    |   lname    |  position  | sex |    dob     |  salary  | branchno**
2. the 'branch' table:   **branchno |    street    |   city   | postcode**

Thank you kindly

Comment: Please show anything that you have attempted.  This is a pretty basic join/group by query that someone with a basic knowledge of SQL should know how to do.

Comment: Agree.  `| position | sex |` is the only thing that caught my eye.

Comment: That's just a count query on Staff, you don't need the branch table at all to achieve the result you want???

Comment: I've tried loads of things, none of them right, I'm not sure how to approach it. I've searched online but it is hard to actually find something that is helpful.

@Tony You do because the branch table may contain a branch that has no employees, so it must be joined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really basic query, and if you have problems solving it, just break it down step by step:

What is it you want to get? A count of people in a certain branch. How do you choose what information to display? With a `select`statement.

What do you want to do with the information before you show it? You want to count it with a `count()`aggregate function.

Where do you get the data from? A table, selected with a `from`statement.

And finally, you only want from a specific branch so what do you do? You filter the results with a `where`clause.

And putting it all together you get this:

```
SELECT COUNT(staffno) FROM Staff WHERE branchno = 1
```

If you want the branch with number 1.

Edit: I just noticed the comment you made about branches without employees, and taking that into account you need the branch table too.

```
SELECT b.branchno, COUNT(staffno) AS StaffCount FROM branch b
LEFT JOIN staff s ON b.branchno = s.branchno 
-- WHERE b.branchno = 1  -- optional filter
GROUP BY b.branchno
```

Using a `left join`between the tables means that you'll get all rows from branch and the matching rows from staff.

Comment: Hi psw, yes that is exactly what I wanted, I shall dissect this query many times. Thank you for all the edits!